# ng grid cell template not updating the changed values

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to refresh the ng grid data on button click which is out side the ng grid, the normal cell values are refreshing (the modified values are updated) but the cell templates are not refreshing based on the value changes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some failing code or show any errors you're getting?

Comment: Are you doing something outside of the angular framework?  I.E. jQuery, $ajax or otherwise.  If so, you can use $timeout or $apply to force angular to execute a model change.  If you don't post more information, there's no way to tell what's happening.

Comment: please setup a plunker

Comment: Yes, please refine the issue and state which versions of angular and ng-grid we are talking about. See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hUaIJdtIvtfLgrFGrgbo?p=preview Clicking UPDATE will age Tiancum very quick. Are you using ajax? How do you code your templates?

Comment: @Lee Abraham, user2724215: I gave a solution, would you mind seeing if it works for you ?

Answer (score 2):

As there is no example associated with the question, I will go ahead and create my own solution to update the cell template (apply a CSS class) automatically if the dataSource changes for the `ng-grid`.

Here is the working plunk. http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/QpDBeHkFAwOtuexVuO5T/

I have moved the logic for applying the cell template from `ng-grid` to the `controller` as a function that returns a `string` which is a CSS class name.

This solution will work for any changes to `ng-grid`'s data source as every single time a change happens to the data source, the corresponding `angular` code will be executed which in turn calls a function inside `controller` that gets the style data.

Answer to your question: It all depends on the way we design our cell templates.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.addBigPerson = function(){
      $scope.myData.push({name:'abc', age: 75});
    }
    
    $scope.addSmallPerson = function(){
      $scope.myData.push({name:'abc', age: 34});
    }
  
    $scope.getClassForPerson = function(age){
      if(age > 40)return 'green';
      return 'red';
    }
  
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
                     {field:'age', displayName:'Age', cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="getClassForPerson(row.getProperty(col.field))"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'}]
        };
});
```

```css
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
 color: white;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        <button ng-click="addBigPerson()">add big</button>
        <button ng-click="addSmallPerson()">add small</button>
    </body>
</html>
```